# Jenkins on Windows - "SSLHandshakeException"

Tags: java, ssl, jenkins, ssl-certificate

I'm currently trying to get Jenkins to work on a windows pc.
Using the msi downloaded via https://www.jenkins.io/download/ and installing it was successfull but now I'm facing the problem that jenkins can't update or install plugins.
I get an "SSLHandshakeException"-Exception when I try to install updates.

I researched quite a lot now and added an ssl certificate via console to the cacerts file in the java home directory(https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44778). Still I can't get any update or plugin.

At the moment I have no clue why jenkins can't connect to the update server and I'm pretty lost here... my attempts to install jenkins via docker resulted in jenkins not finding any directory on the master pc so I guess I'll have to stick with the msi solution...

Hopefully somebody here got an Idea what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You need to ignore the ssl certificate, check here [this tutorial](https://www.thetopsites.net/article/53666882.shtml)

Comment: The link is broken.